# WPF: GridView with an "index" column

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, listview

I have a standard `ListView` with a `GridView`. Now I want one of the columns in the `GridView` to be the 1-based index of that line in the list, as such:

```
| # | First name | Last name |
| 1 | John       | Smith     |
| 2 | Anne       | Anderson  |
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Are the columns loaded from a database?

Comment: That sounds to me a good usage for the DataGrid Control:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx

Comment: @Tony: No, the columns are static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to answer this one, since the columns are static, you can create an ItemSource binding to the array or whatever is holding the items.

```
<GridView ItemSource="{Binding ArrayName}" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource gridViewTemplates}" 
          Name="Whatever" ...>
</GridView>
```

And now we have to set the template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="gridViewTemplates">
    <TextBlock Row="{Binding RowNumber}" Column="0" Name="Id" 
           Text={"Binding Id"} />
</DataTemplate>
```

Please do the changes to whatever suits you best.

More Info on [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFDataBinding08012008233147PM/WPFDataBinding.aspx).